# Share IOS calendar appointment to third party via custom app

Tags: ios, calendar

I have a personal assistant app where one feature we would like to implement is to give the user the ability to share one of his calendar appointments with his virtual PA to manage on his behalf via XMPP. Eg add more participants, coordinate catering, phone ahead if the user is running late etc.

After a lot of research I can't come up with a solid way to do this. Can anyone point me in the direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Event Kit Framework. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html